# WordPress: You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server

Tags: wordpress, error-handling

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/ on this server.

Let me know how I can solve it.

I tried it by rename the WordPress plugin file but it didn't work.

Comment: There are many solutions available for WordPress forbidden error on internet, Please try those solutions first to solve your issue.

Comment: A bit of extra context about how you are running this would make it easier to diagnose the problem

Answer (score 0):

Go into your server files and make a local backup of your .htaccess file, then delete it from the server. If it fixes the issue, then you'll know it was corrupt and you'll want to go to settings -> permalinks and hit 'save changes' to generate a new one.

If it doesn't work, upload the backup back in.